# Encountered error in BCP. Client unable to establish connection due to prelogin failure

Tags: sql-server

We're into SQL Server 2008R2.
I received the following erorr :

```
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Client unable to establish connection due to prelogin failure.
```

Using the following script :

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(200)  
BEGIN 
    set @cmd = 'bcp.exe "' + 'SELECT 1111' + '" queryout ' + '"' + 'C:\ePay\test.txt' + '"' + ' -S ' + 'HOEXDB01\XPDBPRD1\' + ' -c -q -C1252 -t , -U ' + 'usr_apps_tst' + ' -P ' + 'test1234$$'
    print @cmd
    execute xp_cmdshell @cmd
end
```

Thanks and appreciate any help
Elmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`+ 'HOEXDB01\XPDBPRD1\' +`

To

`+ 'HOEXDB01\XPDBPRD1' +`